# Python: How to change the color of a plotted signal depending on point in time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, signals, series

I'm using Python/matplotlib. If I have a time series signal as well as start and stop indices for different phases of an experiment how could I color the signal by phase? So for example, the signal would be red from 0-100 seconds,blue from 101-300, yellow from 301-365, etc.

This is what I tried:

```
for phase in phases:
    plt.plot(signal[phase.start:phase.end])
    plt.show()
```

It breaks the signal up into all the phases correctly but plots them on top of each other instead of sequentially. If you can see, here is a picture from a MATLAB graph that I am trying to reproduce:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTHCH.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to also provide the X argument to plot. I can't tell what it would be for you without a more complete example (i.e. a piece of code I can copy and paste that will just run) but I suspect you need to change your plotting command to something like: `plt.plot(np.linspace(phase.start,phase.end,len(phase),signal[phase.start:phase.end])` If you can provide a minimal example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can give more specific recommendations.

Comment: Thank you lanhi! I had a little bit more work to do, but your comment set me on the right path. Solved!